# Rails gon, something similar in Node.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, variables

I saw that Rails [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem can get Server-side variables into client-side JS.

Now is the question, is there something similar for Node.js (Express.js)?

Answer (score 0):

At didn't understand clearly your question at a first glance.

It seems that [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) is something alike you may want.

According with its home page:

> **Pure JavaScript.** Write your entire app in pure JavaScript. All the same APIs are available on the client and the server — including
>   database APIs! — so the same code can easily run in either
>   environment.